# How do I ensure that Two Way Binding really is two way

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding, user-controls

Continuing my experimentation with building wpf user controls.  I now have the basic end user customisation features fixed and the navigation control can bind to a data source (an ICollectionView).  I have noticed though (despite setting the binding to the view to be Two Way) that when I click the buttons on the navigation control the records displayed in the grid are in sync;

[image]

but if I select a row on the Grid the Record x of Records textbox on the navigation control does not get updated to reflect the new selection on the grid.

[image]

Obviously I was naieve in thinking that just setting the binding to be two way would have the desired effect.  What have I missed?

This is an mvvm scenario if that makes any difference.

Thanks

Comment: did you bind to the SelectedIndex of your datagrid?

Comment: No I didn't.  I've been building a stand alone dataNavigation user control for use in multiple forms across multiple projects.  Currently it has a Dependency property of type ICollectionView, to which it is bound to the view model with mode set to two way but that is all.

Comment: If you want to make sure that two way binding is set or that you are properly updating all your properties consider setting a converter in your binding. Without actually converting anything you will be able to keep trace by debugging when or what happens. I hope this helps you any futher.

Comment: can you pls post your xaml binding for your "2" of 81 in your usercontrol and the binding for the ICollectionView to your UserControl

Comment: <DataNavigator:DataNavigator HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,19,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" DataIcv="{Binding ProductsCollectionView, Mode=TwoWay}" RecordsCount="{Binding ProductsCount}"/>