# How do I keep track of the CollectionView.CurrentPosition

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have built a wpf user control with aN ICollectionView dependencyProperty defined like so;

```
Public Shared ReadOnly DataIcvProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DataIcv", GetType(ICollectionView), GetType(DataNavigator), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Nothing))


<Description("The CollectionView (as an ICollectionView) to be passed to the DataNavigator control"), Category("Navigation Data Source")>
Public Property DataIcv As ICollectionView
    Get
        Return GetValue(DataIcvProperty)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As ICollectionView)
        SetValue(DataIcvProperty, Value)
    End Set
End Property
```

The purpose of the control is to act as a data navigator. When used in an mvvm scenario I can bind it to a models collectionview and navigate through records on a grid bound to that same model's collection view.  However if I actively selet rows in the grid (and move through those using the keyboads up and down arrows whilst the row selection in the grid changes the current position in my Navigator control does not get updated.  You can see an illustration of what I mean [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27533660/how-do-i-ensure-that-two-way-binding-really-is-two-way).

I think what I need to be doing is keeping track of the DataIcv.CurrentPosition.  How do I do that in code from within my Data Navigator?

Thanks

Comment: `CollectionView`s are not so appropriate for MVVM as they are very UI based. You'd be much better creating a simple collection property and another property to data bind to the `SelectedItem` property and then doing your filtering and/or ordering from the view model. Then to 'navigate' through your records, just change the value of the data bound `SelectedItem` property.

Comment: Sheridan  Thanks for your thoughts.  What sort of simple collection property had you in mind when you made your comment?

Comment: A `public` CLR property whose type is a collection of some sort... nothing complicated. Typically, `ObservableCollection<T>` is the preferred choice, where `T` is replaced with whatever type of data you are using. And make sure to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on that type and view model.

Comment: Unfortunately in this instance the originating datasource is a C1 LiveLinq ClientView (of t) which cannot be converted to an observableCollection (of t), but can produduce an ICollectionView.

Comment: The `ClientView<T>` class implements the `IEnumerable` interface, so it can easily be enumerated and thereby copied into any collection.