# Tracking the CurrentChanged event of an ICollectionView declared as a dependencyProperty

Tags: wpf, vb.net, dependency-properties

I have an ICollectionView declared like so;

```
Public Shared ReadOnly DataIcvProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DataIcv", GetType(ICollectionView), GetType(DataNavigator), New PropertyMetadata(Nothing))


<Description("The CollectionView (as an ICollectionView) to be passed to the DataNavigator control"), Category("Navigation Data Source")>
Public Property DataIcv As ICollectionView
    Get
        Return GetValue(DataIcvProperty)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As ICollectionView)
        SetValue(DataIcvProperty, Value)

    End Set
End Property
```

On which I would like to keep track of the CurrentChanged event.  So in the constructor of a wpf userControl (in which this property is declared I have added the following:

```
AddHandler DataIcv.CurrentChanged, AddressOf OnDataICVCurrentChanged
```

and then added the following

```
Public Sub OnDataICVCurrentChanged(ByVal sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles internalIcv.CurrentChanged

    'Do whatever needs doing when the record in the ICollectionView changes

End Sub
```

When I then compile the usercontrol and use it in a separate project I get a NullReferenceException on the AddHandler line in the Constructor of the control (without any inner exception details).

What do I need to do to keep track of the current Changed event of the DataIcv so that I can have elements of my user control react properly to those changes?

Thanks

EDIT

This relates to the issue I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27533660/how-do-i-ensure-that-two-way-binding-really-is-two-way).  Essentially I want the navigator control to reflect the fact that the end user might select rows on the grid independently of the navigator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, when you try to subscribe to the `CurrentChanged` event in your constructor, the `DependencyProperty` **DataIcvProperty** has a default value `Nothing` (as you specified in your property registration). So the `NullReferenceException`.

You could solve this with a `PropertyChangeCallback` (see [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745795(v=vs.110).aspx)).

I come from the C# world and cannot guarantee the right syntax for VB.NET, but this approach surely will work:

```
Public Shared ReadOnly DataIcvProperty As DependencyProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register("DataIcv",
    GetType(ICollectionView), GetType(DataNavigator),
    New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
        Nothing,
        New PropertyChangedCallback(AddressOf OnDataIcvChanged)))
```

Then you need to implement the `OnDataIcvChanged` static method, which will be called every time the property value changes.

```
Private Shared Sub OnDataIcvChanged(ByVal d As DependencyObject, ByVal e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    If e.OldValue IsNot Nothing
        RemoveHandler (e.OldValue As ICollectionView).CurrentChanged, AddressOf OnDataICVCurrentChanged
    EndIf
    If e.NewValue IsNot Nothing
        AddHandler (e.NewValue As ICollectionView).CurrentChanged, AddressOf OnDataICVCurrentChanged
    EndIf
End Sub
```

**Update:**
If your event handler method is not static, then you should access it via the object instance:

```
Private Shared Sub OnDataIcvChanged(ByVal d As DependencyObject, ByVal e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    Dim DataNavigator instance = d As DataNavigator        
    If e.OldValue IsNot Nothing
        RemoveHandler (e.OldValue As ICollectionView).CurrentChanged, AddressOf instance.OnDataICVCurrentChanged
    EndIf
    If e.NewValue IsNot Nothing
        AddHandler (e.NewValue As ICollectionView).CurrentChanged, AddressOf instance.OnDataICVCurrentChanged
    EndIf
End Sub
```

Edit: Code That eventually worked:

```
 Public Shared ReadOnly DataIcvProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DataIcv", GetType(ICollectionView), GetType(DataNavigator), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Nothing, New PropertyChangedCallback(AddressOf OnDataIcvChanged)))


<Description("The CollectionView (as an ICollectionView) to be passed to the DataNavigator control"), Category("Navigation Data Source")>
Public Property DataIcv As ICollectionView
    Get
        Return CType(GetValue(DataIcvProperty), ICollectionView)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As ICollectionView)
        SetValue(DataIcvProperty, Value)

    End Set
End Property

Private Shared Sub OnDataIcvChanged(ByVal d As DependencyObject, ByVal e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    Dim dn As DataNavigator = CType(d, DataNavigator)



    If e.OldValue IsNot Nothing Then
        RemoveHandler dn.DataIcv.CurrentChanged, AddressOf dn.OnDataICVCurrentChanged
    End If
    If e.NewValue IsNot Nothing Then
        AddHandler dn.DataIcv.CurrentChanged, AddressOf dn.OnDataICVCurrentChanged
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub OnDataICVCurrentChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Record.Text = (DataIcv.CurrentPosition + 1).ToString

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Thank you so much for your explanation.  I have one question relating to your OnDataIcvChanged Sub.  sould there not be some reference to the dependency object itself (Ie the DataNavigator control) So One might have as the first line Dim dn as DataNavigator = Ctype(d,DataNavigator).  If that is the case how ought we to be writing the Remove and Add handler lines which should presumably refer to the dependency object (dn).

Comment: Yes, of course. If your `OnDataICVCurrentChanged` method is not static, then you need an object instance to add or remove the event subscription for. So you could change the static `OnDataIcvChanged` method to acces the related object.

Comment: Well I managed to get vb code that compiles but this is only firing when the actual collection changes, not when different items within it are selected. I have posted a link at the bottom of the question relating back to a question I asked which is the root cause of the problem that I am trying to solve.

Comment: Do you set the `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` property of your grid to `True`?

Comment: Hi finally realised what I had done wrong and made a slight change to the code, which I have added as an edit below your answer which I have now marked as correct and answered.  I cannot thank you enough for pointing me in the correct direct direction after a day and a half of sheer frustration.